# Spring Batch - Pass args into job parameters builder

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have my xml : launch-context.xml contains :

```
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource"  value="file:#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}" />
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper"/>
</bean>
```

I want to save arg[0] as the filePath. Is this the correct way? I am not sure

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JobParameters param =  new  JobParametersBuilder().addString("input.file.name", args[0]).toJobParameters();
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("launch-context.xml");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is point `filePath` to `args[0]`. You should put a setter method in your Config class:

```
public static void setFilePath(String path) {
    this.filePath = path;
}
```

and add to your main method (assuming the name of your other class is `Config`):

```
Config.setFilePath(args[0]);
```

Comment: ...is the setter static?